# How to get acting to product price rule in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rules

**/magento-catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**

```
<span class="old-price">
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
        'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'skip_adjustments'  => true,
        'economy_settings'  => $block->getEconomySettings()
    ]); ?>
</span>
```

Function **$block->hasSpecialPrice()** looks like

```
public function hasSpecialPrice()
{
    $displayRegularPrice = $this->getPriceType(Price\RegularPrice::PRICE_CODE)->getAmount()->getValue();
    $displayFinalPrice = $this->getPriceType(Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE)->getAmount()->getValue();
    return $displayFinalPrice < $displayRegularPrice;
}
```

How can i find what cause discount to this product. For example i want to know what price rule discount is percentage or value.
it could be price rule for product catalog or price rule for cart.
Any ideas? Thanks!